# Webflux Chaining multiple Mono

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-reactor

I am new to reactive programming (Spring webflux) and wanted how to best handle this use case.
I have a reactive service call (**getAccount**) that returns **Mono** and I want to chain it with another service call **getBooks** that returns **Mono<Set>** and one final synchronous call **transform** that perform some kind of transformation and returns something like **Mono<Set>** How would I chain and return the transformed data in the form of **Mono<Set>** while logging warnings when **getAccount** or **getBooks** are returning empty? Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do as an example.

Given some fake services here

```
 public static Mono<String> getAccount(String name){
        return Mono.just(name);
    }
    public static Mono<Set<Book> getBooks(String title){
        return Mono.just(Sets.newHashSet(new Book(title + "One", "Author One"),
            new Book(title +"Two", "Author Two"),
            new Book(title + "Three", "Author Three")));

    }
    public static LibraryBook transform (Book a){
        return new LibraryBook(a.getTitle(), a.getAuthorName(), "someUniqueId");
    }
```

I wanted to get the account of a given user and find all the books that he/she borrowed and transform the books and return the value as a Mono<Set> while logging warnings where appropriate

Here is my start

```
public Mono<Set<LibraryBook>> getBorrowedBooks(String userId) {
     return getAccount(userId)
            .flatMap(account ->  getBooks(account))
            .log()
            .map(books -> books.stream().map(book -> transform(book)).collect(Collectors.toSet()))
          
}
```

However, I am not sure if mixing reactive and stream is a bad thing and it just does not look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

Since you cant modify the **getBooks** method, you can construct your **getBorrowedBooks** method in the following way to avoid dealing with stream.

Note- the loggers and exceptions are just for example. You can handle empty scenarios in different ways too.

```
public class MyApp {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApp.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<LibraryBook> libraryBooks = getBorrowedBooks("Abhi").collectList().block();
    libraryBooks.forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  public static Mono<String> getAccount(String name) {
    return Mono.just(name);
  }

  public static Mono<Set<Book>> getBooks(String title) {
    return Mono.just(Sets.newHashSet(new Book(title + "One", "Author One"),
        new Book(title + "Two", "Author Two"),
        new Book(title + "Three", "Author Three")));

  }

  public static LibraryBook transform(Book a) {
    return new LibraryBook(a.getTitle(), a.getAuthorName(), "someUniqueId");
  }

  public static Flux<LibraryBook> getBorrowedBooks(String userId) {
    return getAccount(userId)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
          LOGGER.error("No account found");
          return Mono.error(new NoAccountFoundException());
        }))
        .flatMap(account -> getBooks(account))
        .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
          LOGGER.error("No books found for account");
          return Mono.error(new NoBooksFoundForGivenAccountException());
        }))
        .map(MyApp::transform);
  }
```

---

Compile wise this is correct. But logically, I think this is incorrect because you are not considering the definitions of mono and flux.

Mono is a stream of 0..1 elements.
Flux is a stream which can emit 0..N elements.

The method **getBooks** (as the name suggests) should emit more than 1 element (which is Book here) for a given title. So it's return type should be flux instead of Mono of a collection.

Even you can take examples from the Spring's reactive repository methods:

[image: ReactiveCrudRepository]

Now the idea of removing duplicates and storing a collection in a hashset , in reactive world, is synonymous to calling **distinct()** on a Flux of elements.

[image: Flux.distinct()]

So your **getBooks** method should look like:

```
  public static Flux<Book> getBooks(String title){

    return Flux.just(new Book(title + "One", "Author One"),
        new Book(title +"Two", "Author Two"),
        new Book(title + "Three", "Author Three"))
        .distinct();

  }
```

And your **getBorrowedBooks** method should look like:

```
  public Flux<LibraryBook> getBorrowedBooks(String userId) {
    return getAccount(userId)
        .flatMapMany(account -> getBooks(account))
        .log()
        .map(book -> transform(book));
  }
```

Comment: My apologies if my question was not clear enough.  The getBooks and getAccount are existing calls that I dont want to change the signature. Also Mono<Set<Book>> return type for getBooks means that you'll get asynchronously a full Set of Book elements in one shot and I don't think that's a problem. My question is mainly in properly implementing getBorrowedBooks method where I can log warnings when getAccount or getBooks return empty.

Comment: @dawit I have updated the answer. Please check if it satisfies your needs